# UIImageView caching data from API

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, caching, image-caching

When I scroll my UITableView quickly, imageView shows the wrong images from API. (i.e. Samsung image shown in Brexit article and so on).

Here`s an extension allowing me to download images(maybe I can change something here):

```
extension UIImageView {
    func donwloadImage(from url: String) {
        let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: URL(string: url)!)
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { (data,response,error) in

            if error != nil {
                print(error)
                return
            }

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.image = UIImage(data: data!)

            }
        }
        task.resume() 
    }

}
```

Comment: why don't you use 3rd party lib for this? If you want I can give you links of few libs.

Comment: Yes, maybe i can give it a try, thank you!

Comment: There should be no need to use a third-party dependency for something like this - you're just complicating your code base for no good reason.  Without seeing the tableView code we can't be certain, but it's almost definitely due to the image download being async and not quick enough for fast scrolling, so it shows the image from the last time the cell was used.  Consider clearing the previous image or setting a default in `cellForRowAt` or pre-caching images.

Answer (score 0):

Try any of the following lib:

https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImage

https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher

Comment: @Kwon Min-sik is it working for you? if you need any help, please comment.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the example that shows correct handling. Please have a try.

```
class CustomViewCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

private var task: URLSessionDataTask?

override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()
    task?.cancel()
    imageView.image = nil
}

func configureWith(url string: String) {
    guard let url = URL(string: string) else { return }

    task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
        if let data = data, let image = UIImage(data: data) {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.imageView.image = image
            }
        }
    }
    task?.resume()
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

definitely use a library for this.

advice

https://github.com/kean/Nuke

nuke is very simple.

```
Nuke.loadImage(with: url, into: imageView)
```